# Postgres - Regroup rows with at least one common attribute

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table :

```
Letter | Figure
-------|-------
   A   |    1
   B   |    1
   B   |    2
   C   |    2
   C   |    3
   D   |    3
   E   |    4
```

I would like to group rows that share a common letter OR figure. Result should then be :

```
Letter | Figure | Groupment
-------|--------|-------
   A   |    1   |   I
   B   |    1   |   I
   B   |    2   |   I
   C   |    2   |   I
   C   |    3   |   I
   D   |    3   |   I
   E   |    4   |   II
```

I know I can define a postgres function and re-scan the all table for each new row, but I'm trying to find something a little bit less unoptimized.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possibly related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/create-a-grouping-based-on-chains-of-pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tricky but fun. Using a recursive query:

```
with recursive
  v(l, f) as (
    -- select Letter, Figure from table
    values ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('C', 3),  ('D', 3), ('E', 4)
    ),
  r as (
    select *
    from (
      select array[l] as l, array[l] as al, array[f] as f, array[f] as af, 1 as g, 1 as n
      from v order by l, f limit 1
      ) a
    union all
    select CASE WHEN g.newgrp THEN g.l ELSE r.l || g.l END, r.al || g.l,
           CASE WHEN g.newgrp THEN g.f ELSE r.f || g.f END, r.af || g.f,
           CASE WHEN g.newgrp THEN g + 1 ELSE g END, n+1
    from r
    join lateral (
      select CASE WHEN newgrp THEN ARRAY(SELECT l FROM v WHERE l<>ALL(r.al || g.l) AND f<>ALL(r.af || g.f) ORDER BY l, f LIMIT 1) ELSE l END AS l,
             CASE WHEN newgrp THEN ARRAY(SELECT f FROM v WHERE l<>ALL(r.al || g.l) AND f<>ALL(r.af || g.f) ORDER BY l, f LIMIT 1) ELSE f END AS f,
             newgrp
      from (
        select l, f, g.l = '{}' AND g.f = '{}' as newgrp
        from (
          select COALESCE(ARRAY(SELECT l FROM v WHERE f =ANY(r.f) AND l <>ALL(r.l)), '{}') as l,
                 COALESCE(ARRAY(SELECT f FROM v WHERE l =ANY(r.l) AND f <>ALL(r.f)), '{}') as f
          ) g
        ) g
      ) g on (true)
    where (not g.newgrp or (g.newgrp and g.l <> '{}'))
    ),
  g as (
    select distinct on (g) l, f, g
    from r
    order by g, n desc
    )
select v.l as Letter, v.f as Figure, g.g AS Groupment
from v
join g on (v.l =any(g.l) or v.f =any(g.f))
order by 3, 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work great on small sample, but when I tried it on a larger sample like  'SELECT generate_series(1,100000) AS id, md5(random()::text)'   (my database is actually 100k rows) it fails. Is the recursive approach the most optimized for large db ?

Comment: @BenoîtFabre how did it fail? What error did you get? 100000 rows in PostgreSQL is not much at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `WINDOW` function `lag() over()`:

```sql
SELECT
  l,
  f
  ,is_different
  ,SUM(is_different::int) over(ORDER BY l,f) groupment
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      l,
      f,
      COALESCE(NOT(l = lag(l) over(ORDER BY l, f) OR f = lag(f) over()),false) is_different
  FROM t
) a;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63953/9/0)